# Helper Class - Error Unable to start activity ComponentInfo:

Tags: android, class, oncreate, runtimeexception, illegalstateexception

Error Unable to start activity ComponentInfo: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()

I´m experimenting with seperating the code and the use of a helper class. (Created different Java files)
What I did is created an Activity Java file that is registred in the Manifest and I didn´t register this following class (Java file):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
....


public class DeviceMonitor extends Activity {

    boolean laag=false;
    int level=-1;
    double batterylevel=-1;


    public boolean GPSEnabled() {

    final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    if ( !manager.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER ) ) { // NO GPS ENABLED
        //ErrorMessage.append(R.string.enablegps);
        //ErrorMessage.append("\n");
        Log.d("StartPrepare","GPS DISABLED");
        return false;
                    } else {
        Log.d("StartPrepare","GPS ENABLED");
        return true;
                    }
    }
```

I removed the OnCreate() method, is this correct?
Should I have registred in the Manifest, if yes, how?

I received the following error while calling from the registred Activity like this:

```
DeviceMonitor MyDevice = new DeviceMonitor();
if (MyDevice.GPSEnabled()){gpsenabled=true;}else{gpsenabled=false;fout=true;}
```

Error:

> E/AndroidRuntime(1912): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start
>   activity
>   ComponentInfo{package}:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to
>   Activities before onCreate()

Anybody that can give me some light on the helper classes (I´m kind of new in Java/Android) and has any clue what the error can cause? I tried to add the OnCreate() method, but it didn´t help.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Context is available inside onCreate() method of an activity. You have removed onCreate()  which might be causing the issue. If you want to treat this as Helper class, why you extended Activity? I would suggest have some method over here which will be called from your activity. While calling the method your activity need to pass the context.

Comment: So the method in the activity that is calling should pass the context? Can you give me en example in code? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do NOT do this...

```
DeviceMonitor MyDevice = new DeviceMonitor();
```

`DeviceMonitor` extends `Activity` and you should never create an instance of an `Activity` using `new`. An Android `Activity` is a special-case class and shouldn't be treated like a normal Java class.

If you want to start an `Activity` you need to do it using `startActivity...)` or one of the other 'start' methods.

If you want a 'helper' class just create a standard Java class which doesn't extend anything. When you create an instance of it from your main `Activity`, pass the `Activity` `Context` to it in its constructor then use that to access Android services etc. Example...

```
public class DeviceMonitor {

    Context mContext = null;

    public DeviceMonitor (Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** To create your helper and pass a `Context` from your main `Activity` do this...

```
// An Activity IS a Context so pass 'this'
DeviceMonitor MyDevice = new DeviceMonitor(this);
```

Comment: thanks! I don´t want to start another activity, so I indeed should remove the extend activity. Though I´m not sure how I should solve the unavailable methods. If I don´t extend the class actity, suddenly the getSystemservice is not available for example. Do I still need the onCreate() method?

Comment: As I said, use the `Context` you passed into the helper class as in `mContext.getSystemService(...)`. No, your helper is not an Android component so `onCreate(...)` is not a relevant method for it.

Comment: Also see the edit to my answer on passing `this` to the helper's constructor as the `Context`

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your

```
boolean GPSEnabled
```

after onCreate() method is callded in your class or service.

Comment: Sorry, if I ask stupid questions, but I´m still figuring all this out. @thinksteep, if I don´t extend the Activity class, my getSystemService is not recognized (not available). What is the correct way to handle this? Further I put back the onCreate() method, but it doesnt solve the issue. Do I have to register the file in the Manifest?